# Is $[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Is $[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ (as a subspace of $\Bbb R$)? 
The segment $[0,1]$ is a connected space and $[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ is disconnected. Is it enough to prove that $[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, that suffices. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766514/homeomorphism-preserve-compactness-and-conectedness

Comment: You could also note that $\{2\}$ is open in the first and no singleton of $[0,1]$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

No.
Because in $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$ we have that $\{2\}$ is open and $\not\exists a \in [0,1] : \{a\}$ is open.
Also we can use that $[0,1]$ is coneccted and $[0,1) \cup \{2\}$ is disconeccted:
If $\exists \phi: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1) \cup \{2\}$ homeomorphism then we have that $[0,1]=\phi^{-1}([0,1)) \cup \phi^{-1}(\{2\})$ and $\phi^{-1}([0,1)) \cap \phi^{-1}(\{2\}) = \emptyset$ and this implied that $[0,1]$ is disconeccted !!!!!!! Absurd.