# A general question about homeomorphism from $(0, 2)$ to $(0, 1]\cup(2, 3)$ (topology)

Tags: general-topology

Is $(0, 2)$ homeomorphic to $(0, 1]\cup(2, 3)$? If it is, let $f$ be their homeomorphism, then we know that $(0.5, 1]$ is open in $(0, 1]\cup(2, 3)$. So $f^{-1}((0.5, 1])$ is open in $(0, 2)$, but I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @HenryChan "but I don't think that is possible" what makes you think so? Anyway, there is no such homeomorphism because the first space is connected and the second one is not. This post is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @Anne Bauval Because I’m thinking that the the pre image of (0,1] must be open. Also the pre image of (2,3) must be open as well. But these are two open sets where union of those can’t be connected open set

Comment: This post was indeed a duplicate. See the connectedness argument in [Is $[0,1)\cup\{2\}$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559845/is-0-1-cup-2-homeomorphic-to-0-1)

Comment: Your last comment agrees with my first one but does not answer my question. $f^{-1}((0.5, 1])$ had nothing to do in this argument. Never mind since everything is now clear.

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you so much